# How i can calculate sum with filter and show result in table

Tags: java, android, listview, gridview, xml-parsing

I use:

```
Android studio 2.2.2
sdk: min 19 target 25
ksoap2 library for get SoapObject from web-server.
```

I had got result with this structure:

```
<Date>2016-11-04T00:00:00</Date>
<Hours>8</Hours>
<EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>; 
<EmployeeFirstName>My</EmployeeFirstName>
<Date>2016-11-05T00:00:00</Date>
<Hours>6</Hours>
<EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>; 
<EmployeeFirstName>My</EmployeeFirstName>
<Date>2016-11-06T00:00:00</Date>
<Hours>2</Hours>
<EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>; 
<EmployeeFirstName>My</EmployeeFirstName>
<Date>2016-11-05T00:00:00</Date>
<Hours>6</Hours>
<EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>; 
<EmployeeFirstName>My2</EmployeeFirstName>
<Date>2016-11-04T00:00:00</Date>
<Hours>4</Hours>
<EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>; 
<EmployeeFirstName>My2</EmployeeFirstName>
```

Questions is:

1. (For not technical reasons i cannot do it in sql or webserver and return recordset or xml with result)
   What android-object better use(collection, array, btree...) for grouping by "EmployeeID" and get sum("Hours")?
2. What android-object better use for show it in Activity and user can filtering it?

For my example i what get table like this:

```
EmployeeFirstName    SumHours
My                      16
My2                     10
```

User in interface must have possibility "push the button" and filtering table by:

```
"EmployeeFirstName" = My2 
or "EmployeeFirstName" = My
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you can use tech in Android to parse data from xml file or string. You can visit the tutorial with the url https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm
2. Then you can use HashMap or others in java collection to calculate sum hours of different employee.
3. For show content, you can use ListView and BaseAdater. You can add one line to show title by using such as LinearLayout or others.

Answer (score 0):

try using custom list view with custom adapter. And then set a model(Getter/Setter). You can then fetch data for a particular entity for eg:

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){

listview.get(position).get(EmployeId).equals("1"){
int Hours = Hours + listview.get(position).get(Hours);
}
}
```

This way you can sum all the fields and put it on edit text for your other requirement of allowing user to edit.